# Having trouble with python decryption and encryption algorithm

Tags: python, encryption

Not sure why this is not working. This is supposed to encrypt and decrypt a sentence. I'm getting back the right letters, but they are not in the right 
order.

```
def get_encrypt(original_text,dictionary):
    #4
    match= ""
    for base in original_text:
        match += dictionary[base]
    return match

def rev_look(encrypted_text, dictionary):
    match_key = []

    for key in dictionary:
        i = 0
        for base in encrypted_text:
          print(base)
          if dictionary[key] == base:
            match_key.append(key)
          i += 1
    return match_key


def main():
    print('* Simple Substitution Cipher Tool *')
    #Define the dictionary
    dictionary = {' ':' ','a':'p', 'b':'h', 'c':'q', 'd':'g', 'e':'i', 'f':'u', 'g':'m', 'h':'e', 'i':'a', 'j':'y', 'k':'l', 'l':'n','m':'o', 'n':'f', 'o':'d', 'p':'x', 'q':'j', 'r':'k', 's':'r', 't':'c', 'u':'v', 'v':'s', 'w':'t', 'x':'z', 'y':'w', 'z':'b'}
    #2
    original_text =(input('Please enter the original text: '))
    #3
    encrypted_text = get_encrypt(original_text,dictionary)
    print('The encrypted text is: ', encrypted_text)
    print('The decrypted text is: ', rev_look(encrypted_text,dictionary))


main()
```

Comment: Maybe, iterate over the characters in the text then *find* that character in the dictionary - not the other way around. - but this seems to be working OK for me. `'foo' --> 'udd' --> 'foo'`

Answer (score 0):

You are not getting them in order because you are first iterating through dictionary (the first `for` loop). I modified it a little bit

```
def rev_look(encrypted_text, dictionary):
    match_key = []        
    for base in encrypted_text:
        for key in dictionary:
            if dictionary[key] == base:
                match_key.append(key)

    return match_key
```

Note: When you are traversing through dictionary, there is **NO GUARANTEE** that you will get the elements **in order**